# Effect of arteriole dilation on vein

Tags: physiology

If  an arteriole leading to a capillary bed is dilated will the pressure in the vein coming out from the bed decrease ? Will the velocity of blood in the vein change ?

Comment: Do we assume that the dilation of the arteriole was under independent regulation and not a consequence of systemic release of a vasodilator, i.e. all other conditions are assumed to be constant?

Comment: @SatwikPasani It was under independent regulation.

Answer (score 3):

All else being **constant**, velocity of the Venous blood will be reduced.

The Flow-Rate Equation: Q=AV

- Q = Flow Rate
- A = Area (of the "pipe")
- V = Velocity of the Fluid

If we assume that the body will try to maintain a constant *Q*, then an increase in the *A* of the Arteriole means a **reduced** *V* to compensate and a corresponding drop in Venous fluid velocity.

If we start to assume that things are not constant, then the story becomes more complicated. Since Venous pressure is largely maintained by musculature and other actions, *not* heart contractions (though the system is essentially closed-loop), an increase in Arteriole flow-rate doesn't *always* correspond to an increase in Venous flow-rate. When there is an imbalance - either due to mechanical interference or something else - conditions like [subcutaneous edemas](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/subcutaneous+edema) can occur where the interstitial (between-tissues) fluid builds up enough to cause discomfort or damage.

*Normal Disclaimer: I am not a medical professional. The above us based upon an Undergraduate level of knowledge.